# Mongoose Query is not fetching match data from multiple table

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, mern

I am using nodejs,mongodb and mongoose. This query is not  fetching match data from user and order table. I have read mongoose docs and alot of other articeles. It's according to it but doesn't fetch match data from tables.

**Query code:**

```js
       const data = await order
      .find({ admin_id: req.params.id })
      .populate("orderRelate");
      console.log(data);
```

**My user and order schema code is:**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    mobile_no: { type: Number, required: true },
    profilePic: { type: String, defaut: "" },
    owner: { type: Boolean, defaut: false },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    customer_id: { type: String, required: true },
    admin_id: { type: String, required: true },
    order_type: { type: String, defaut: "normal" },
    order_status: { type: String, required: true },
    order_price: { type: Number, required: true },
    order_address: { type: String, required: true },
    order_pickDate: { type: String, required: true },
    order_pickTime: { type: String, required: true },
     orderRelate: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);
```

Please let me know if anyone know why I am facing this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `findById` maybe it's work

Comment: I used findById too but giving same issue. Everthing seem fine as according the mongoose docs but still not fetching match data from tables.

Comment: Let me know if you know where I am wrong

Comment: @luckyboy sure.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how you wrote your middleware function but..

await Order.find({orderRelate: req.user.id})

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).